# "Difficult" sorting under some conditions

Tags: python, list, sorting, object

Alright. This may be difficult but I have been struggling for quite a bit without great improvement, so I'd like to know what you guys think.

Suppose I have the following list of objects:

```
objects = [
        {'id': '1', 'w': 0.20}, 
        {'id': '1.1', 'w': 0.80}, 
        {'id': '1.2', 'w': 0.20},
        {'id': '1.3', 'w': 0.30},
        {'id': '1.1.1', 'w': 0.60},
        {'id': '1.1.2', 'w': 0.70},
        {'id': '1.1.3', 'w': 0.40},
        {'id': '1.2.1', 'w': 0.30},
    ]
```

I want to sort this list by 'id' (e.g. `'1', '1.1', '1.1.1', '1.1.2', '1.1.3', '1.2', '1.2.1', '1.3'`) but then all the elements with the same parent need to be ordered by 'w' (in reverse). What do I mean by 'same parent'?. Well, '1' is parent of '1.1', '1.2' and '1.3'. Likewise, '1.1' is parent of '1.1.1', '1.1.2', '1.1.3' and '1.2' is parent of '1.2.1'. To illustrate this better, imagine this is a representation of a thread with nested comments ('1' is the original post, '1.1' is its answer, and so on).

For now, I have been able to reach the following form:

```
[ [ {'w': 0.2, 'id': '1'} ], [ {'w': 0.8, 'id': '1.1'}, {'w': 0.3, 'id': '1.3'}, 
{'w': 0.2, 'id': '1.2'} ], [ {'w': 0.7, 'id': '1.1.2'}, {'w': 0.6, 'id': '1.1.1'},
{'w': 0.4, 'id': '1.1.3'} ], [ {'w': 0.3, 'id': '1.2.1'} ] ]
```

As you can see, each nested list comprises elements which are children of other element. For example, the second nested list `[ {'w': 0.8, 'id': '1.1'}, {'w': 0.3, 'id': '1.3'}, {'w': 0.2, 'id': '1.2'} ]` contains all the children of the element `[ {'w': 0.2, 'id': '1'} ]`. Additionally, each nested list is ordered by 'w'.

The final result should be something like this (assuming chaining all the inner lists - `list(itertools.chain(*b))`):

```
{'id': '1', 'w': 0.20}, {'id': '1.1', 'w': 0.80}, {'id': '1.1.2', 'w': 0.70}, 
{'id': '1.1.1', 'w': 0.60}, {'id': '1.1.3', 'w': 0.40}, {'id': '1.3', 'w': 0.30}, 
{'id': '1.2', 'w': 0.20},   {'id': '1.2.1', 'w': 0.30}
```

Basically, first goes the parent, then its children (ordered by 'w'), and the same applies to each element (if it has children, of course - here `{'id': '1.3', 'w': 0.30}` doesn't have children so we don't need to do anything with it).

I have tried a few things (too convoluted to be worthy of explanation). I ended up with quite a few conditionals and an ugly code.

How can I accomplish this sorting?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The sample you posted as the desired results isn't sorted as per your description. `1.1.2` is before `1.1.1`, for example; and `w` is sorted arbitrarily.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid w is sorted in reverse, the results do make sense if you look carefully.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Yes, as jamylak said, 1.1.2 is before because it's a children of 1.1 so as per my description, they should be ordered by 'w' (first 0.70 and then 0.60). Sorry, I missed that clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple sort will not solve your problem, because it is not possible to compare any two elements and immediately know when one comes before another (the weight of the parents may change the ordering).

You need to process the list into a tree structure and then extract it in order:

```
tree = {}

for d in objects:
    ids = d['id'].split('.')
    w = d['w']
    # walk into the tree, creating nodes as necessary
    subtree = [0,tree]
    for n in ids:
        if n not in subtree[1]:
            subtree[1][n] = [0,{}] # w, list of nodes
        subtree = subtree[1][n] # recurse
    # subtree is now the relevant node, set w
    subtree[0] = w

## now we have a tree:
## >>> pprint.pprint(tree, width=10)
## {'1': [0.2,
##       {'1': [0.8,
##              {'1': [0.6,
##                     {}],
##               '2': [0.7,
##                     {}],
##               '3': [0.4,
##                     {}]}],
##        '2': [0.2,
##              {'1': [0.3,
##                     {}]}],
##        '3': [0.3,
##              {}]}]}

# now walk the tree and extract the nodes:
result = []
def walk_subtree(subtree, path=[]):
    keyweights = [(subtree[key][0], key) for key in subtree]
    # walk through nodes at this level, outputting.
    for weight, key in sorted(keyweights, reverse=True):
        result.append(('.'.join(path + [key]), weight))
        walk_subtree(subtree[key][1], path=path+[key])

walk_subtree(tree)

##>>> pprint.pprint(result)
##[('1', 0.2),
## ('1.1', 0.8),
## ('1.1.2', 0.7),
## ('1.1.1', 0.6),
## ('1.1.3', 0.4),
## ('1.3', 0.3),
## ('1.2', 0.2),
## ('1.2.1', 0.3)]
```

Comment: @jnnnnn This looks great, although as I said in the other answer, I was avoiding trees to sort answers. At least, this is done without going to the database. I will take a look at your code in a few hours (it's a bit late here) but thank you very much :-).

Comment: @RobertSmith - I don't think you *can* avoid trees or tree-like structures of some sort here, since what you're trying to do is in a very basic sense tree-based (parents/children/etc).

Comment: @jnnnnn I'm really impressed with this solution. Let me ask you, is this a standard procedure? Seems like it's using the fact that dictionaries are passed by reference to construct the tree while actually modifying the subtree. It's also exposing lists in the subtree to change the weight of that node and as lists are also mutable, these changes are performed in the tree. Surely you were thinking in checking nodes and creating them if they didn't exist but it's not so straightforward. I need to take a closer look at some parts of walk_subtree, but as I said, very nice solution.

Comment: If it's hard to understand then it's not a nice solution :/.   A clear solution would use a small class to store the node (instead of a two-element list).

Answer (score 0):

Sort with a comparator. That is, you write a method looking like

```
def comparator(x, y):
    ## some code that sets value to -1 if x is "less than" y
    ## or 1 if x is "greater than or equal to" y.
    return value
```

Then call `objects.sort(comparator)` and you should be set.

This way you only have to deal with comparing two items at a time. As long as you're consistent, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: And then when you move to 3.x it will blow up, since 3.x doesn't support comparators.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Not everyone is planning on moving to 3, not least because it unnecessarily removes features like this.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams What do you mean by 3.x doesn't support comparators? Prohibitive high time it will take to run through all the elements?.

Comment: @RobertSmith: Nah, you just write a "less than" operator for the object: http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__

Comment: Oh, now I understand. I thought 3.x meant 3.1, 3.1.1, 3.2, 3.2.1 etc :-). Well, definitely this can work but I'm afraid it will be a bit messy. Furthermore, I'm genuinely concern with performance because I could easily reach 10.x.x (x < 10, though). It could be dangerously bad to scale.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to figure out the order of any two of these objects based on just their data, though!  For instance the order of 1.1.2 and 1.2.2 *depends on the weights of 1.1 and 1.2*, so your comparator would have to look up the appropriate parent weights in the full data list... I suppose that's doable.